# Python: Call a Function1 inside Function2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I would like to split the code of this function, pushing out the code (name_city = city.get () ... cursor.execute ...., and results). I attach two codes: the first of the app working well, while the second of what I would like to get but I can't.

```
def write():
    if categoria.get() == "test1" and sottocategoria.get() == "test2":
    
        name_city = city.get()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TableExample WHERE Name_city=?',(name_city,))
        results = cursor.fetchone()

        cursor.execute('SELECT Test1 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
        word2 = cursor.fetchone()

        inhabitants = results[2]
        surface = results[3]

        text.delete(1.0,END)
        text.insert(tk.END, f"{name_city} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}")
```

Now if I wanted to eliminate us from inside (name_city = city.get () ... cursor.execute .... and results), creating the function def data_city, in order to insert it in the function (def write), not inside If, ​​but out, how can I do? I've tried that, but it doesn't work. The problem is that the def data_city function is as if it is being ignored How to invoke the data_city function inside the write function? (but outside of If, not inside If). Thank you

```
def data_city():
    name_city = city.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TableExample WHERE Name_city=?',(name_city,))
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    return results


def write():

    data_city() #ERROR/PROBLEM

    if categoria.get() == "test1" and sottocategoria.get() == "test2":
       
    cursor.execute('SELECT Test1 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
    word2 = cursor.fetchone()

    inhabitants = results[2]
    surface = results[3]

    text.delete(1.0,END)
    text.insert(tk.END, f"{name_city} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}")
```

For greater completeness and clarity, I am attaching the complete bootable code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

window=Tk()
window.title("aaaaa")
window.geometry("750x750")
window.configure(bg='#78c030')

con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Scrivania/aaaa/Database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

### PULSANTI ###

def write():
    if categoria.get() == "test1" and sottocategoria.get() == "test 1.2":

        name_city = city.get()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TableExample WHERE Name_city=?',(name_city,))
        results = cursor.fetchone()

        cursor.execute('SELECT Test1 FROM TableExample2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
        word2 = cursor.fetchone()

        inhabitants = results[2]
        surface = results[3]

        text.delete(1.0,END)
        text.insert(tk.END, f"{name_city} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}")
   

button2 = Button(window, text="Button2", bg='white', command = 
write)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=5, y=330)

### TEXTBOX MULTILINE ###
text = Text(window,width=63,height=38)
text.pack()
text.place(x=180, y=24)

### CATEGORIA E SOTTO CATEGORIA ###
cat=StringVar()
sub_cat=StringVar()

def change_val(*args):
    if cat.get() == "test1":
        sottocategorias = ["test 1.1", "test 1.2", "test 1.3"]
        sottocategoria.config(values=sottocategorias)
    else:
        sottocategorias = ["aaaa"]
        sottocategoria.config(values=sottocategorias)
    
categorias=["test1", "test2", "test3"]
categoria=ttk.Combobox(window,value=categorias,
textvariable=cat,width=16)
categoria.place(x=5, y=25)
cat.set("Scegliere categoria")

sottocategorias=["aaaa"]
sottocategoria=ttk.Combobox(window,textvariable=sub_cat,
value=sottocategorias,width=16)
sottocategoria.place(x=5, y=55)

cat.trace("w",change_val) 

### COMBOBOX ###

### CAMPIONATO COMBOBOX ###
def combo_nation():
    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Nation FROM TableExample')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

### SQUADRA COMBOBOX ###
def combo_city(event=None):
    val = nation.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT Name_city FROM Info WHERE TableExample = ?', (val,))
    result = [row[0] for row in cursor]
    city['value'] = result
    city.current(0)
    return result

nation=ttk.Combobox(window,state="readonly")
nation['value'] = combo_campionati()
nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_squadre)
nation.place(x=5, y=150,height = 25, width = 180)

city=ttk.Combobox(window,state="readonly")
city.place(x=5, y=180, height = 25, width = 180)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: And what exactly "doesn't work"? e.g. what is the stack trace?

Comment: You have failed to reproduce your code's actual indentation.  We cannot tell where the code of a function, or the body of an `if` statement, ends.  It's easy to do this right - paste the code, select it all, then press the `{}` button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Removed the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] since it's not specific to Python2 or Python3. And you're clearly on Python3.6+ since you're using f-strings. Welcome to StackOverflow. See how you can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us solve your problem and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @sophros The app starts up regularly. What doesn't work is the data_city function. It is as if it does not exist. It is not called back

Comment: I modified the question, adding more details. I have made the question clearer and more complete. I also added more code. I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: Help me, please

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a return on the data_city function? Try:

```
def data_city():
    name_city = city.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Info_Squadra WHERE Name_city=?',(name_city,))
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    return results
```

Comment: Tried. That's no good. Maybe I'm wrong to call the data city () function inside the write function. To call it, just write data_city ()?

Comment: I modified the question, adding more details. I have made the question clearer and more complete. I also added more code. I hope you can help me. Thank you